# Why the INDIRECT excel method doesn't work as expected

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

These two methods bring to a different result. Why?

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A$1:$A$5);A1))))
```

Correct value!! I get TRUE! It works!

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A$1:INDIRECT("$A$5");A1))))
```

Uncorrect value!! I get FALSE! It doesn't work as expected!!

In A1 there is the following value:

```
0,"Annotations","10:00:00:00","10:00:08:23","Testo"
```

Instead, in "FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx" there are the following values from A1 to A5:

```
"Abbigliamento"
"Vestito"
"Porta"
"Testo"
"Statua"
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to use INDIRECT?

Comment: The list of values in the file FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx is actually really long, much more than 5 values, and it will be updated with the addition of other values. I want to point to the latest cell dynamically using this function:

=ROW(OFFSET(A1;COUNTA(A:A)-1;0))

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the last cell:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A$1:INDEX('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A:$A;MATCH("zzz";'[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A:$A));A1)))
```

Comment: Your function was just missing a $.
It's actually:

=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A$1:INDEX('[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A:$A;MATCH("zzz";'[FILTER_OBJECT_SETTING.xlsx]Filter Object'!$A:$A));$A4)))

How did you solve this problem so quickly? I'm really shocked? You are really great!! :D
Please let me know!